# How can I edit the citation style in the text using biblatex with alphabetic style?

Tags: biblatex, citing

I'm using the alphabetic citation style within the biblatex package, which generally works fine for me if I cite other publications. But my professor want me to edit the citation in the text if I cite an own publications or these of my students in the following way:

[XYZ22*] for my own publications

[ABC21**] for the thesis of my students

Here a small example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
backend=bibtex,
style=alphabetic, 
autocite=inline, 
sorting=nyt, 
sortcase=false,
url=false,
hyperref=auto,
maxnames=10,
maxbibnames=3, %max 3 Namen im Literaturverzeichnis, sonst "et al."
maxalphanames=1
firstinits=true,
maxcitenames=1,
isbn=false,
labelnumber,
defernumbers=true,
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{filecontents*}{\References.bib}
    @article{Myself2018,
    author = {Myself, I},
    title = {Whatever},
    journal = {Proceedings of ICFUN},
    year = {2018},
    doi = {10.15544},
    keywords = {Mys},
    }

    @article{Student2019,
      author = {Student, My},
      title = {Whatever 2},
      journal = {Proceedings of ICFUN},
      year = {2019},
      keyword = {Stu}
    }
    
    @book{Boge2021,
      author = {B{\"o}ge, Alfred and B{\"o}ge, Wolfgang},
      year = {2021},
      title = {Technische Mechanik},
      address = {Wiesbaden},
      publisher = {{Springer Fachmedien Wiesbaden}},
      isbn = {978-3-658-34153-4},
      doi = {10.1007/978-3-658-34154-1}
     }

\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\References.bib}



\begin{document}


This is my work \cite{Myself2018}. This is the work of my student \cite{Student2019}. This is the work of someone else \cite{Boge2021}. 


\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The result should be in the text:

> This is my work [Mys18*]. This is the work of my student [Stu19**]. This is the work of someone else [Bog21].

And of course there should be three different biblographies, which I already managed by using the keywords:

```
\printbibliography[title={Authors Publications}, keyword={Mys}, heading=subbibliography]
\printbibliography[title={Students Publications}, keyword={Stu}, heading=subbibliography]
\printbibliography[title={Further Publications}, keyword={Mys}, notkeyword={Stu}, heading=subbibliography]
```

Any help would be great!

Many thanks in advance and best regards

Comment: It seems like you have two different users https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/277813/questioner20220805 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/277815/questioner20220805, which means you have effectively lost control over your question. You can ask Stack Exchange staff to [merge your accounts, so you regain control](//tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Answer (score 2):

In the `alphabetic` style there is no convenient way to add a marker after the citation label, so we redefine the `cite` bibmacro.

If you want the stars to also appear in the bibliography, redefine `labelalphawidth`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  backend=bibtex,
  style=alphabetic, 
  autocite=inline, 
  sorting=nyt, 
  sortcase=false,
  url=false,
  maxnames=10,
  maxbibnames=3,
  maxalphanames=1,
  firstinits=true,
  maxcitenames=1,
  isbn=false,
  labelnumber,
  defernumbers=true,
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newbibmacro{cite:addmarkers}{%
  \ifkeyword{Mys}{*}{}%
  \ifkeyword{Stu}{**}{}%
}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \printfield{labelprefix}%
    \printfield{labelalpha}%
    \printfield{extraalpha}%
    \ifbool{bbx:subentry}
      {\printfield{entrysetcount}}
      {}%
    \usebibmacro{cite:addmarkers}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelalphawidth}{%
  \mkbibbrackets{#1\usebibmacro{cite:addmarkers}}}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Myself2018,
  author   = {Myself, I},
  title    = {Whatever},
  journal  = {Proceedings of ICFUN},
  year     = {2018},
  doi      = {10.15544},
  keywords = {Mys},
}
@article{Student2019,
  author   = {Student, My},
  title    = {Whatever 2},
  journal  = {Proceedings of ICFUN},
  year     = {2019},
  keywords = {Stu},
}
@book{Boge2021,
  author    = {B{\"o}ge, Alfred and B{\"o}ge, Wolfgang},
  year      = {2021},
  title     = {Technische Mechanik},
  address   = {Wiesbaden},
  publisher = {{Springer Fachmedien Wiesbaden}},
  isbn      = {978-3-658-34153-4},
  doi       = {10.1007/978-3-658-34154-1},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
This is my work \cite{Myself2018}.
This is the work of my student \cite{Student2019}.
This is the work of someone else \cite{Boge2021}. 

\printbibliography[title={Authors Publications},
  keyword={Mys}, heading=subbibliography]
\printbibliography[title={Students Publications},
  keyword={Stu}, heading=subbibliography]
\printbibliography[title={Further Publications},
  notkeyword={Mys}, notkeyword={Stu}, heading=subbibliography]
\end{document}
```

[image: This is my work [Mys18*]. This is the work of my student [Stu19**]. This is the work of someone else [Bög+21].]